# ProcessBuilder launching of X11 app fails with java7, worked with java6

Tags: java, macos, r, exec, x11

I have a server process written in java that uses ProcessBuilder to launch a command line program (the R statistic engine) that can cause X11 to start up when run with the Apple 1.6 jvm. However, this does not work with the Oracle 1.7 jvm. I get no error messages on stdout, stderr, or in the console.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

The java process listens to the network and needs to start R with command line options that can very, i.e. it can start/stop R multiple times. There would be a tremendous amount of work required to launch R outside of java.

Comment: *"I get no error messages on stdout, stderr, or in the console."*  You mean you actually consume & display both output streams of the `Process`?

Comment: Show us some code. Also, are you sure that it is the launching code that is not working? (Have you isolated the Issue?).

Comment: R can use X11 *only* if the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set properly. Also make sure you start X11 specifically using `X11()` so that you're not relying on implicit device choice (which is why you probably don't see anything - it's just using another device). Finally, if you need graphics there are better ways to use R from Java (see JRI/rJava + JavaGD for example which allows you do route all graphics into your Java application)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to upgrade your Java to >= 1.7.0.11.

We had a similar problem where we executed a wine program out of our java application using ProcessBuilder under CentOS 5. It worked with Java 1.6 but broke with Java 1.7.0.9. After upgrading to 1.7.0.11 the problem was gone.